# Options to build a page in stages

Tags: c#, asp.net

not too sure how I should describe my topic the best way, but basically my problem is as follows. My page output will be as below (simplified format)

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<section id="sec1"><!-- some .Net code used to generate this block, data source is xml, output is HTML --></section>
<section id="sec2"><!-- some other .Net code used to generate this block, data source is xml, output is HTML --></section>
<section id="sec3"><!-- This data is generated by using a webservice, return is HTML --></section>
</body>
</html>
```

So far nothing special, but the content for "sec3" can sometimes take a while to be returned, and the rest of the page waits in vain at that moment. As soon as all the data is available and the content is fully rendered, the page is provided to the client.

I therefore want to be less depending on the time taken for some sections to generate, and would like to output a section to the client as soon as available, so the page builds up in stages, rather than all at once. I know there are options to speed up the processes using parallel or asynchronous methods, but in the end the page is still depending on the slowest block before it's rendered, and that's the behavior I'd like to avoid.

Anyone that can put me in the right direction ? Any tips or good reading advice on the topic would be highly appreciated. We're using C# / asp.net 4.5

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest loading sec3 via an ajax call (easy using jquery) once the page has loaded.

Basically:

1) Separate the sec3 markup and store it in a separate aspx page
2) When the main page loads, obtain the sec3 section via an ajax call.

If you look at the jquery documentation for ajax you should be able to get this up and running in no time.

Comment: Thanks already, one of the issues with this approach (correct me if I'm wrong) is that the ajax call result would not be indexable by Google or any other search engine, which would be another problem

Comment: Interesting - the other problem of course would be if people have javascript disabled, although I'm not sure if that is an issue worth considering anyway these days?  Okay, well is there any possibility of you caching the web service response?

Comment: This might be of use:http://moz.com/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate

Comment: Nice article indeed , it's not serving our needs as such since browser compatibility is also an issue (another one...) but it's definitly something I need to take a closer look at for another project I'm working on. Caching is unfortunately not a real option, since the data is not 'fixed' but a dynamic return. static blocks are already cached, but the dynamic one is the bottleneck